# Google Charts Threshold?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

Is it possible to develop a threshold with Google Charts?

I have a Google combo chart with 5 columns. In theory, I wanted to use the addRange formatter function to change the color of the 2nd column if it was under 50. (Basically it's a motivation tool. Your daily goal is to make atleast 50 calls. If you do not, the chart shows up as red, if you do, then it is the default color)

This is my current code that creates the chart, just not the formatting. Thanks.

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('string', 'Rep');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Yesterday');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Last 7');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Last 30');
    data.addColumn('number', 'The Bar');

    $("#data-table thead th").each(function(){

        var initials = $(this).text();

        var yesterday = parseInt($("." + initials + ".Yesterday").text());

        var seven = parseInt($("." + initials + ".seven").text());

        var thirty = parseInt($("." + initials + ".thirty").text());

        data.addRow([initials, yesterday, seven, thirty, 50]);

    });

  // Set chart options
  var title = $("#data-table caption").text();
  var options = {'title':title,
                 seriesType: 'bars',
                 series: {3: {type: "line"}},
                 hAxis: {title: 'Rep'},
                 vAxis: {title: 'Outbound Calls'}

                };

    var formatter = new google.visualization.TableColorFormat();

    formatter.addRange(50,0, 'red', '#000');

    formatter.format(data, 1);

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('call-log'));
  chart.draw(data, options);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to do a quick check on your data, and set a variable for the color of series two based on what the value of that column is.

So currently you have the following options code:

```
  var options = {'title':title,
                 seriesType: 'bars',
                 series: {3: {type: "line"}},
                 hAxis: {title: 'Rep'},
                 vAxis: {title: 'Outbound Calls'}

                };
```

If you change this slightly, you can make series 2 colored based on a variable:

```
  var options = {'title':title,
                 seriesType: 'bars',
                 series: {
                            3: {type: "line"}
                            // set the color of column 2 (series #1) via variable
                            1: {color: colorvar}
                         },
                 hAxis: {title: 'Rep'},
                 vAxis: {title: 'Outbound Calls'}

                };
```

Then you can just create a javascript function to determine what the value for column 2 is, and color appropriately:

```
var colorvar = "#FF0000";
if (data.getValue(0,1) >= 50)
  colorvar = "#000000";
```

This way, if the value is under 50, it will be read. Otherwise it will change to black. Then when you create the options, it will use whatever color is dictated by this function. That way you can color based on the value in column 2.